# C# WPF ComboBox.ItemTemplate is still useable?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have tried to make Binding using ComboBox.ItemTemplate but it is saying the following error:

Error XDG0012 The member "ItemTemplate" is not recognized or is not accessible.

Here you can see a part of my implementation:

[image]

Anyone can help? Is there another way to implement this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo: In your code, the `ComboBox` element is closed (`/>`), so the `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` element is not contained in it.

Comment: Thank you @padeso for your answer. I am a new here to learn WPF so, I had not known ComboBox.ItemTemplate should be inside <ComboBox> </ComboBox>. Now it is clear.